# Rails collection_select form adds selected value to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a Rails 4 app that is a game database. The models relevant to this question are:

- Game
- Genre
- GameGenre (the relationship table)

It has a games/new form, which creates new game records.

Within that form, I want a sub-form which allows the user to add genres. I envision it working as follows:

1. The user selects a genre from the select input. The options are populated from `Genre.all`
2. When the user hits the Add button, the id of the selected genre is pushed to an array. They can add as many genres as they want to this array.
3. When the user hits Save on the main game form, the app uses an `add_genre` function I've defined to create `GameGenre` relationship records for each of the genres.

This is my `games/new.html.erb` view code at present:

```
<div id="game-genres-form">
  <%= fields_for(@game.game_genres.build) do |f| %>
    <div><%= hidden_field_tag :game_id, @game.id %></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :genre_id, "Add a genre" %>
      <div class="input-group">
        <%= f.collection_select :genre_id, Genre.all, :id, :name,
                                        {}, {:class=>'form-control'} %>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-default" %>
        </span>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This does not work, because `fields_for(@game.game_genres.build)` is incorrect. In fact, at present when I click 'Add' it submits the new-game form and creates a game record but doesn't add the genre.

I think what I need to know is, what do I use instead of `fields_for(@game.game_genres.build)` to pass the submitted genre to a new array? And how can I set up this up in `games_controller.rb`?

I realise `<div><%= hidden_field_tag :game_id, @game.id %></div>` won't be necessary (since `game_id` doesn't exist until the new game record has been saved).

I hope I'm making sense, thanks for the help.

---

These are my current associations, they are missing `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. I'm not too worries about this at the moment - I mainly want to know the right type of form to use, and how to make it add each genre to a hash/array.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :game_genres,  foreign_key:  :game_id,
                          dependent: :destroy

  has_many :genres, through: :game_genres

class GameGenre < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :genre

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :game_genres,  foreign_key:  :genre_id,
                          dependent: :destroy

  has_many :games, through: :game_genres
```

Comment: Can you post your associations as well.  You should have allows_nested_attributes for the fields that are accepting nested attributes.

Comment: Added them @ruby_newbie

Comment: @ArupRakshit Nothing to offer at the moment sorry, I'm a hobbyist. I'm looking for a partner on a project, but it pays nothing right now. If you'd still be interested let me know.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing something like this in your game model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :game_genres ,allow_destroy: true
```

or you can try this to save your genres in your view

```
<%= collection_select(:category, :ids, Category.all, :id, :category, { :selected => @categories.map{|m| m.id}}, {:multiple=>true}) %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am missing those lines, but I mainly want to know about the type of form I need to use and how to post the selected genre to a hash or array.

Comment: there are lots of ways do save your selected genres in your db.. you could use collection_select and no need to make things complicated with nested form_for..